# Pourquoi le nom COVID-19 est-il féminin (« la COVID-19 ») ?

Tags: vocabulaire, genre, terminologie, santé-et-médecine

Pourquoi le nom *COVID-19* est-il féminin (« la COVID-19 ») alors que *coronavirus* et *SRAS-CoV-2* sont masculins (« le coronavirus/SRAS-CoV-2 ») ?

Comment: Merci de dire où tu as entendu/lu « la covid-19 ». Car c'est [beaucoup plus fréquent au masculin](https://bit.ly/2UcJeAY). L'emploi [au féminin](https://bit.ly/2UcyuTm) semble d'origine québécoise.  Mais comme on peut le constater dans [cet article du quotidien du médecin](https://bit.ly/3dnKcly) ça dépend de ce que désigne Covid-19, qui est un peut employé comme un adjectif qualifiant soit le syndrome (masculin) ou  la maladie (féminin).

Comment: L'OMS utilise le féminin dans ses communications officielles. Notez que le/la COVID-19 est une maladie, pas un syndrome.

Comment: @None C'était à l'origine dans _LaPresse_ concernant l'épouse du Premier ministre du Canada. La République emploie surtout [_le coronavirus COVID-19_](https://www.gouvernement.fr/info-coronavirus). _On constate une [hésitation_](http://www.granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26557671).

Comment: n.b. remplacer _est_ par _serait_ vu que Robert et Larousse mentionnent les deux genres mais avec une séquence inversée, si j'ai bien compris ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

L'acronyme "COVID" signifie "COronaVIrus Disease", soit "maladie due à un coronavirus". Il ne désigne pas le virus lui-même. Il est donc logique qu'en français, le mot prenne le genre du mot "maladie" et soit féminin.

On peut voir effectivement que l'OMS utilise le terme au féminin (voir [ici](https://www.who.int/fr/emergencies/diseases/novel-coronavirus-2019))
Cet [article](https://ici.radio-canada.ca/nouvelle/1657532/covid-linguistique-virus-epidemie-wuhan-usage) donne un bref historique de l'usage au sein même de l'OMS, il semble que ce soit un ajustement récent.

Cependant, force est de constater, en parcourant l'actualité et en écoutant la radio ou la télévision, que la majorité des locuteurs (du moins en Europe) ont pris l'habitude d'utiliser l'acronyme COVID comme un nom masculin (sans doute par confusion entre le virus et la maladie). Comme le terme a fait une irruption très soudaine et récente dans le langage courant, il sera intéressant de voir si, sur le long terme, l'usage garde le masculin ou le féminin.

Il est tout à fait logique que "coronavirus" soit masculin, sur base du mot "virus".

"SARS-CoV-2" (acronyme de Severe Acute Respiratory Syndrome Coronavirus 2) désigne le virus et non la maladie, il est donc également logique que cet acronyme soit masculin.

Comment: Je me demande si n'a pas aussi joué le fait que le nom d'une autre maladie associée dans l'imaginaire collectif aux grandes épidémies, le choléra, est masculin et commence par les mêmes sons (kɔ).

Comment: Le petit Robert a tranché pour **[le covid](https://www.francetvinfo.fr/culture/livres/covid-au-masculin-et-sans-majuscule-dans-le-petit-robert-2022_4618473.html)**.

Comment: ... et sans majuscule ! Bravo Robert !

Comment: Désolé mais non, malgré le titre des dépêches, le Robert dit que le mot est « masculin ou féminin », donc plus fréquemment au masculin (en France). Robert disent « «c’est l’usage qui fait loi. Si le féminin est adopté au Canada francophone, le masculin est pour l’instant majoritaire en France, où l’avis de l’Académie française a été rendu tardivement, alors que le masculin était déjà bien implanté ». Robert n'a rien tranché, il n'en a ni la vocation ni la capacité. cc @jlliagre

Comment: @némésie-t-île Tu as bien sûr raison. Là où le Robert à "tranché", c'est en reconnaissant la primauté de l'usage au lieu de s'enferrer dans un prescriptivisme obstiné. L'année dernière, on a été matraqués avec ce covid au masculin, toute la France disait **le** covid. Lorsque certains ont défendu le féminin, il était déjà illusoire de penser qu'un mot ayant un tel degré de reconnaissance puisse voir son genre modifié. Que la situation soit différente au Québec n'est pas un problème. Tout le monde sait de quoi il s'agit quand vous dites parfois une job...

Comment: L'explication par le genre de "maladie" qui est representee par le D de covid ne me convient pas vraiment... Bitcoin est, selon le Larousse un nom masculin, pourtant, "coin" signifie "Piece" en anglais qui est un nom feminin...